# PDO not searching when value is not set

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to search genre and artist columns only if they are set. So if one of them is set to 'all' I would declared them 'NULL' and not search that column. This is what I came up with but it is not working.

```
if($genre=='all')
{
    $genre=NULL;
}
if($artist=='all')
{
    $artist=NULL;
}

$query=$conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM songs WHERE (genre=?) && (artist=?)');
$query->bindValue(1,$genre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(2,$artist,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$array=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: `if($genre='all')` will not do what you think it does. It **sets** the value of `$genre` to `all`, not check if it's `all`. You need to use `==` instead: `if($genre == 'all')`.

Comment: also `$genre=null` with `PDO::PARAM_STR` is not sql `NULL`...

Comment: @Amal Murali I apologize, I made an misstype (I somehow make one in every question...). The line is indeed `if($genre=='all')`. The full code in this part is actually sorting a lot of POST requests.

Comment: and your sql `where clause` always used, even you set `$genre=null;` Need more sofisticated or any numbers of query

Comment: @vp_arth Well, that is exactly the problem. Is there any way to do this without making a query for each possible combination? There are actually a lot more of parameters and possibly hundreds of combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not related to PDO, but to (My)SQL in general.

Try to expand placeholders in your query query and see:

```
mysql> select 1=null;
+--------+
| 1=null |
+--------+
|   NULL |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select 1 && 1=null;
+-------------+
| 1 && 1=null |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you compare a value to null, you get null
if you use null in a logical operator, you get null

So, you need it another way

```
$params = array();
$where  = array();
if($genre && $genre != 'all')
{
    $where[]  = "(genre=?)";
    $params[] = $genre;
}
if($artist && $artist != 'all')
{
    $where[]  = "(artist=?)";
    $params[] = $artist;
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM songs';
if ($where) {
    $sql .= 'WHERE '.implode('&&', $where);
}
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($params);
echo json_encode($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Comment: isn't there a bug with empty `$where` array?

Comment: @vp_arth no, there isn't

Comment: implode returns an empty string on empty `$where`; so - your query ended with `WHERE 1 &&` Is it correct SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try followed:

```
$where = array();
$preps = array();
if ($genre!=='all') { 
  $where[] = 'genre = ?'; 
  $preps[] = $genre; 
}
if ($artist!=='all') { 
  $where[] = 'artist = ?'; 
  $preps[] = $artist; 
}

$where = $where ? "WHERE ". implode(' AND ', $where) : '';


$query=$conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM songs '.$where);
if($preps) $query->execute($preps);
else $query->execute();
$array=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);
```